# Normal vector to a level set and fractional Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

Let $U=\{u\le0\}$ and $\partial U=\{u=0\}$. Suppose $\nabla u$ does not vanish on $\partial U$. Then the (canonical extension of the) normal vector field to $\partial U$ (pointing to the interior of $\mathbb R^n \setminus U$ is given by
$$\nu = \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}.$$

This formula is very helpful in some elliptic problems because it is so related to $\int |\nabla u^2| = -\int u \Delta u.$

What about elliptic problems with the **fractional** Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ ($s \in (0,1)$)?

- Is the existence of a solution in $H^{s}$ or $H^{2s}$ even enough to make sense of the normal vector above?
- Can $\int |(-\Delta)^{s/2}u|^2 = \int u (-\Delta)^s u$ be used to control $\nu$?
- Or do people use a different notion of normal vector?

Comment: Posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Normal vector to a level set and fractional Laplacian](https://mathoverflow.net/q/413905). You can find several posts containing some advice related to cross-posting [on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info).